# Chrome gives error when viewing allocation information in profiler

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-management, profiling

I'm trying to debug and find out where significant allocations are occurring in my program.

I've opened up Chrome Developer Tools, navigated to Memory, and then clicked "Start recording Heap Profile".

After five seconds I stop it, and then select the dropdown on the right and click `Allocation`:

[image]

Upon clicking it, no allocation information is shown, and instead the following error appears in my Chrome console:

```
An error occurred when a call to method 'allocationTracesTops' was requested
TypeError: Cannot read property 'serializeTraceTops' of undefined
    at E.allocationTracesTops (devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker/heap_snapshot_worker.js:1:18630)
    at HeapSnapshotWorkerDispatcher.dispatchMessage (devtools://devtools/bundled/heap_snapshot_worker/heap_snapshot_worker.js:1:47490)
```

I am using the latest version of Chrome on Windows 10 and have all extensions disabled. Is this a bug with Chrome? Is there any better way to determine which portions of your code are performing allocations, along with measuring their impact on the GC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature requires enabling "Record stack traces of allocations". There's also a regression in versions that came after 86.0.4240.75, due to which the view is always empty, even with stack traces enabled.